# Dynamic button and create textbox

Tags: c#

I have a textbox and button on c# form and users can enter number.I create a label which users want and each label have a button.Here if I click those buttons i wanna create textbox but if users continue to click,i want to create more textbox.

```
Button[] Btn= new Button[10];
for (int i = 0; i < labelNumber; i++)
{
    Btn[i] = new Button();
    Btn[i].Text = "Add";
    Btn[i].Location = new Point(40, 100 + i * 29);
    Btn[i].Size = new Size(50,20);
    this.Controls.Add(Btn[i]);
    Btn[i].Click += new EventHandler(addNewTextbox); 
}
```

on the code above; for example; if  `labelNumber == 3` so i have 3 label and 3 button with them, if i click add button i wanna create textbox near thislabel.

```
private void addNewTextbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox[] dynamicTextbox = new TextBox[10];
    Button dinamikButon = (sender as Button);
    int yLocation = (dinamikButon.Location.Y - 100) / 29;
    //int xLocation =  dinamikButon.Location.X - 100;
    dynamicTextbox[yLocation] = new TextBox();
    dynamicTextbox[yLocation].Location = new Point(100, 100 + yLocation * 29);
    dynamicTextbox[yLocation].Size = new Size(40, 50);
    this.Controls.Add(dynamicTextbox[yLocation]);

}
```

here i change textbox y coordinates but i couldn't it for X. if i change this

```
dynamicTextbox[yLocation].Location = new Point(100*x, 100 + yLocation * 29);
x++;
```

it sort equals all of them.

```
Label1 Button1
Label2 Button2
Label3 Button3
```

if i click `Button1` 4 times,it has to create 4 textbox alongside `label1`. and if i click `Button2` 2 times,it has to create 2 textbox alongside `label2`
Please Help ME.

Comment: what happens if user continue clicking one and the same button? is there any limit of how many textboxes can be created?

Comment: I wanna crete textbox.I dont think about that but 6 is enough.
Label1 Button1 textBox1 textbox2 Textbox3
Label2 Button2
Label3 Button3
@IvanStoev

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to keep a list containing the created textboxes in the button's `Tag` property like this

```
private void addNewTextbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var textBoxes = button.Tag as List<TextBox>;
    if (textBoxes == null)
        button.Tag = textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
    var textBox = new TextBox();
    textBoxes.Add(textBox);
    textBox.Location = new Point(100 * textBoxes.Count, button.Top);
    textbox.Size = new Size(40, 50);
    this.Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

This way you not only can add a new text box, but also can easily determine the created text boxes by each button at any time if needed.